# code runs in command prompt but does not run in eclipse

Tags: java, command-prompt, bufferedreader, readline, runtime.exec

The code given below is the code that i try to run in eclipse which returns `stdInput.readLine()` as null when i try to run the command through command prompt it runs successfully what am i doing wrong?

```
public class Recognize {
public String Recog(String name)
{   try {
    String command="java -cp .;C:\\mywork\\Speaker\\marf-0.3.0-devel-20070108-fat.jar SpeakerIdentApp --ident C:\\mywork\\Speaker\\testing-samples\\"+name+".wav";
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
         BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
           BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
       name = "";   
       String s ;
       System.out.println(stdInput.readLine());
       // read the output from the command
      // System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
       while ((s=stdInput.readLine()) != null){
              // System.out.println(s);
               String recog = s;
            //   System.out.println(recog);
               String ex = stdInput.readLine();
            //   System.out.println(ex);
               String sb = stdInput.readLine();
             //  System.out.println(sb);
               if ( recog.equalsIgnoreCase(ex))
               {//System.out.println("ACCESS GRANTED");
                name = recog;
              // System.out.print(recog);
                }
               else if (ex.equalsIgnoreCase(sb))
               {//System.out.println("ACCESS GRANTED");
                name = ex;
               // System.out.println(ex);
                }
               else {//System.out.println("ACCESS DENIED");
                name = "";
       }
```

Comment: Try to specify directory location OR JAR File name in classpath for CLASS "SpeakerIdentApp"

Comment: in eclipse or in my system ??

Comment: In line java -cp .;C:\\mywork\\Speaker\\m...

Comment: i tried that but no use when i tried it in command promt it shows noclasdeffounfexception

Comment: Can you print what you got on stdError stream?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: C:\\mywork\\Speaker\\
SpeakerIdentApp

Comment: Theres at least one problem with your code - but first, a question. Is the SpeakerIdentClass located in the `marf-0.3.0-devel-20070108-fat` JAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must be because eclipse default path is not set by you so try setting eclipse default path according to your requirement